# To make the xml file from string

Tags: android, xml, string

I want to create the xml file from the string i.e I have one String Which I want to convert into xml file,How to do it ?

Comment: can I know why you need this before  giving answer as it looks it is simple

Comment: How does your String look like ?

Comment: see this link it might be useful http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-store-properties-into-xml-file/

Comment: I didnt know about storeToXML, thanks +1

Comment: I have parsed the soap response which contains certain fields that fields I want to store on device as a xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
String pathname="D:\\XML files\\text.xml"; //specify your file path here
FileWriter out=new FileWriter(pathname);
out.write(str); // Assuming that str contains text to be writen in xml file i.e. well formed xml string
out.close();
```

If above does not work,
Write :

```
out.write(str.trim());
```

instead.